# "No resource found and References on non existing library" in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I've been busy with eclipse and stuck for a day with 2 last problems. Can please somebody help me?

1. error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.
2. The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library 'C:\Users\XXX\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\bin\android-support-v7-appcompat.jar'

I know that the Bin folder does not contain the file. And the other problem has to do with the other one. But which library is he looking for and how do I get it loaded in there?

Does anybody know what to do? I've tried almost every solution, but no success so far.

Comment: For problem 1:

Your compile SDK version must match the support library's major version.

Since you are using version 23 of the support library, you need to compile against version 23 of the Android SDK.

Alternatively you can continue compiling against version 22 of the Android SDK by switching to the latest support library v22.
For problem 2:To solve this, I went project>properties>java build path>libraries>add jars>appcompat_v7>libs>, then I selected android-support-v7-appcompat.jar. After this, I went to project>clean. This fixed the problem. Hope you find my hint helpful.

Comment: Hi Sharath, Thanks for the explanation so far! Can you explain how i switch to latest support library v22?

Comment: And for #2 to which one can i add it? To Android dependencies?

Comment: Does problem number solved? change your target sdk to 23 since u r using v23 support library.

Comment: Thanks again, no when i change it to 23 it gives major problems. is there another way to do it? and keeping 22 as target?

Comment: Then change compileSdkVersion to 23,minSdkVersion 14,targetSdkVersion 22.

Comment: I have done that already and that causes major errors more

Comment: Ok leave problem 1.Did you try to solve problem 2? actually i have gone through these errors.I rectified it like i said only.All these are done in manifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand the part of where you have to choose which archive you have to choose to the built path? Do you